# HDL Designer library won't open?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

For some reason, my library in HDL Designer doesn't want to open. I was able to generate and simulate the design files in this library last week. It's strange because when I go to the directory on my computer, all of the .vhd files are there. It's as if my library that contains all of these files is locked or something... Has anyone run into this before?[My project library looks closed/locked, and the design files aren't present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2RLc.jpg)

Comment: You should ask this question on the Mentor support forums

Comment: Qustion on use of a specific vendor tool; unrelated to 'VHDL' or 'HDL'

Comment: @JHBonarius Thanks! can you provide link? I can't seem to find this Mentor forum.

Comment: I geuss [here](https://www.mentor.com/support/en/intro). I don't have a mentor account. Mentor tools are too expensive for a student... ;)

Comment: Did your trial license expire?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I use a normal license that is borrowed from a pool